# What's wrong with my RequireJS dependency chain?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates, requirejs

I'm just getting started with RequireJS and it appears I'm not expressing my dependencies correctly. I'm trying to map a fairly straightforward dependency chain:

`KnockoutJS` depends on `jquery-tmpl` depends on `jquery`

I'm trying not to use `require-jquery`. In my HTML, I do this:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

**My `main.js`:**

```
require(
  {
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min',
        jquerytmpl: "require-jquery-tmpl",
        knockout: "require-knockout"
    }
  },
  ["myApp"],
  function() {
        $(function() {
            console.log('main: triggered');
        });
  }
);
```

**My `require-jquery-tmpl.js`:**

```
define([
  "order!jquery",
  "order!http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"], 
  function() {
    console.log("init tmpl");
  }
);
```

**My `require-knockout.js`:**

```
define([
  "order!jquerytmpl",
  "order!./scripts/knockout-1.2.1.js"], 
  function() {
        console.log("init ko");
  }
);
```

And finally, `myApp.js`:

```
define(["knockout"], function() {
    $(function() { ... }
}
```

What I'm seeing is that knockout-1.2.1.js is getting loaded and evaluated before jquery-tmpl.js. The `console.log`s show that `init tmpl` happens before `init ko`, so the RequireJS callbacks are firing in the right order. But, I added some debug logs in Knockout and I can see that it's getting evaluated way before `init tmpl` happens.

As a result, when I try to `ko.applyBindings()`, it complains that jQuery templates can't be found. The funny thing is that if I manually tell KO to register the default template engine in the callback, it works fine and everything's perfect. But, I think that's just masking the core issue.

Why isn't RequireJS waiting until jquery-tmpl is loaded before evaluating Knockout?

Comment: order! is only supposed to work on require statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to diagnose the actual problem, but I got my dependencies working by using `require` instead of `define` in parts of the module definition. The configuration that works for me looks like this:

**My `main.js`:**

```
require(
  {
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min',
        jquerytmpl: "require-jquery-tmpl",
        knockout: "require-knockout"
    }
  },
  ["myApp"],
  function() {
        $(function() {
            console.log('main: triggered');
        });
  }
);
```

**My `require-jquery-tmpl.js`:**

```
define(["jquery"], function() {
    require(["order!http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"], function() {
        console.log("init tmpl");
    });
});
```

Notice I'm saying `require` jquery.tmpl.js with `order` instead of listing it in the `define` dependencies.

**Same change to `require-knockout.js`:**

```
define(["jquerytmpl"], function() {
    require(["order!knockout-1.2.1.js"], function() {
        console.log("init ko");
    });
});
```

This *fixes* my problem, but I still do not have an explanation for why the `RequreJs` `order` plugin doesn't work correctly with my original definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `order.js` file in your `scripts` directory?

Also, the requirejs site [suggests](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) using require-jquery.js instead of require.js when you also want to include jquery.  I've always used that without problems.

Comment: Yes, I have order.js in the scripts directory. I'd like to avoid the require-jquery.js approach. The way I see it, they're two completely different "things" that shouldn't be tied to each other.